# Condor checked baggage fees with connecting flights to USA

Tags: usa, fees-and-charges, connecting-flights, long-haul, condor

I am looking into one-way flight from Europe to the USA. I have found a flight with 2 connecting flights, using Google Flights (it would book it from Condor):

POZ -> FRA (Lufthansa)
FRA -> VYR (Condor)
VYR -> SEA (Alaska)

[Condor's baggage policy](https://www.condor.com/eu/flight-preparation/baggage-and-animals/regulations-for-flights-operated-by-other-airlines.jsp) states that

> If you have booked a Condor flight that includes connecting flights on
>   another airline, and the departure or destination airport is in USA,
>   Canada or Puerto Rico, the regulations of the airline operating the
>   first flight of the itinerary (including the return journey, providing
>   this is included on the same Condor ticket) will apply to the entire
>   trip.  If Condor is not the airline operating your first flight, a
>   special policy may apply to your entire flight itinerary.
>
> In this case, your free baggage allowance will be the baggage
>   allowance of the airline running the connecting flight in the travel
>   class booked for your Condor flight (Economy, Premium or Business
>   Class).

First flight is Lufthansa and for Economy class that means one free checked baggage up to 23KG and one carry-on up to 8kg.

Checking the same flight at Expedia seems to agree with me - the estimated bag fee for the first checked baggage is 0$ and they look at Lufthansa's rules.

Does that mean that I will be able to get the Lufthansa's baggage rules, i.e. first checked baggage for free, baggage size and weight as accepted by Lufthansa, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody answered: yes, I followed the Lufthansa's baggage rules and everything went fine. My bag was almost 23 kg (22 something) and there was no problem or additional charge.